# Return strings within start and finish integer values?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I need to return every substring within a string array that is contained by the its integer index using for loops and if statements.
I managed to split the array and create a for loop but I am stuck when trying to compare the locations of the values using the variables.

```
string[] text = "The brown fox jumps";
char split = " ";
int cutFrom = '2';
int cutTo = '4';

string[] splitText = text.Split(split);

for (int i = 0; i < splitText.Length; i++)
{
    if (parts[i] == parts[cutFrom])
    {
        return parts[i];
    }
}
```

But this code only returns the "brown" (the 2nd array subtext), and I want to return every word from the second value until the 4th value in the array ("jumps").

Comment: Are you trying to return a *string*, or an *array of strings*?  (Also, your `int`s might not be what you think they are...)

Comment: You need to unpack that first sentence. It's unclear what you mean.

Comment: Presumably your method is declared with a return type of `string`. (It would help if you'd show the complete method.) You could change it to return `IEnumerable<string>` and use `yield return` instead of `return`, or you could return an array or list... But I agree with madreflection - currently it's very unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Additionally, the code you've given would just fail with an exception, as the value of `cutFrom` is 50, massively out of range for the `splitText` array. And you're not using `cutTo` at all...

Comment: First things first, your code will not even compile because of wrong variable assignments. You are assigning a string to an array of strings, a string to a char and a char to an int.
Now, to keep only part of a list in C# you can use the [range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) feature and either return a list of strings or join them with spaces to return a single string.
`splitText[(cutFrom-1)..cutTo] // This will return a list of strings.` OR `string.Join(' ', splitText[(cutFrom-1)..cutTo]) // This will return single string`

Answer (score 2):

Your question was a bit weirdly asked but I've tried to interpret it as best as I can.

Here is the solution for what you said:

```
    private string[] getSubstrings(string text, char split, int cutFrom, int cutTo)
    {
        string[] splitText = text.Split(split);
        string[] output = new string[cutTo - cutFrom];

        for (int i = cutFrom; i < cutTo; i++)
        {
            output[i - cutFrom] = (splitText[i]);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Here is the solution with 1 based indexing which is what I think you wanted (getting the first word only is cutFrom = 1; and cutTo = 2)

```
    private string[] getSubstrings(string text, char split, int cutFrom, int cutTo)
    {
        cutFrom--;
        cutTo--;

        string[] splitText = text.Split(split);
        string[] output = new string[cutTo - cutFrom];

        for (int i = cutFrom; i < cutTo; i++)
        {
            output[i - cutFrom] = (splitText[i]);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear what your approach is here. If you want to return a list of substrings from index `cutFrom` to index `cutTo` from a larger string, then you could approach it like this:

```
    string text = "The brown fox jumps";
    string split = " ";
    int cutFrom = 2;
    int cutTo = 4;
    string[] splitText = text.Split(split);
    List<string> finalStrings = new List<string>();


    for (int i = 0; i < splitText.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i >= cutFrom && i < cutTo)
        {
            finalStrings.Add(splitText[i]);
        }
    }

    return finalStrings;
```